# how to get the second occurence (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a string

```
A323-541-389
```

I want to get the character which in front the second "-" , in this case should be `1` .

How to get that `1` in MySQL?

Is it seach for the second '-' then LEFT?
How to seach for the second '-' instead of the first one?

Comment: are the `-` always at the same position?

Comment: @juergend That's irrelevant.  A simple `explode` then `substr` would work.

Comment: I would say same fromat , must have two '-' but not same position.
S2131928340-1231-123213 may occour

Comment: MySQL has no explode function.

Comment: @juergend Considering most of these questions are asked by people typically "learning" MySQL and PHP, and the fact that his profile lists questions with PHP, I would say he can do this in PHP.  Plus, I would go with the fact that MySQL is typically for data storage, not manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

```
select substring(substring_index("A323-541-389","-",2),-1);
```

There could be other ways too.

```
mysql> select substring(substring_index("A323-541-389","-",2),-1);
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| substring(substring_index("A323-541-389","-",2),-1) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Wonderful..simply amazing

Answer (score 1):

That will be

```
select right(substring_index('A323-541-389', '-', 2), 1)
```

-be aware that your string should always contain at least two `-` symbols, otherwise this will not work. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ce8e/1).

Comment: but i selected "Akj12_1" also why is it?

Comment: yes its work also 'A323-541-389' but something more selected is "Akj12_1"

Comment: Then provide your string which returned such result. Be aware of my note about two `-` symbols in string

Comment: sorry this above selecttion is in the where clause

Comment: my selection sentence whould be 
 select col1 from table_1 where right(substring_index(col1, '-', 2), 1)=1

Comment: Then: describe your _actual_ problem in question, provide your data and expected results and what are you not understanding. I think another question should be used for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39043/discussion-between-user2210819-and-alma-do-mundo)

Answer (score 0):

From the chat comment it looks like you want the value of the field when it has a 1 just before the 2nd "-".

If so you could do this basic SQL:-

```
SELECT *
WHERE LENGTH(col1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col1, '-', '')) >= 2
AND RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 2), 1) = '1'
```

However you could probably use regular expressions instead:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html